# When does var.getClass() return Object?

Tags: java, class

This commit: https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeCommon/commit/704ef84398255d66da104e2b43dec7f2c2aa40c3#diff-0570d221b4c69a232692ff6be6369ea3R79

```
   public static String getIdAndTryRegistration(IProperty<?> property, Block block, String blockId) {
         <snip>
 +                Class<?> blockClass = block.getClass();
 +                while (true) {
 +                    if (blockClass == Object.class) {
 +                        final String originalClass = CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, block.getClass().getSimpleName());
 +                        final String propertyId = originalClass + "_" + property.getName();
 +                        LogManager.getLogger("Sponge").warn("Could not find {} owning class, assigning fallback id: {}", property.getName(),
 +                                propertyId);
```

Adds a comparison and a log statement, when a passed in reference to a Block's class, is equal to Object.class

However, in my own testing

```
package org.spongepowered.test;

public class test {


    public static class Parent{}
    public static class Child extends Parent {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> child = Child.class;
        Class<?> parent = Parent.class;
        System.out.println(child +"::"+parent);
        boolean b = Object.class == child;
        boolean c = Object.class == parent;
        System.out.println( b+"::"+c);

        System.out.println("==============================================");

        Class<? extends Child> child2 = Child.class;
        Class<? extends Parent> parent2 = Parent.class;
        System.out.println(child2 +"::"+parent2);
        //boolean b2 = Object.class == child2;
        //boolean c2 = Object.class == parent2;
        //System.out.println( b2+"::"+c2);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
class org.spongepowered.test.test$Child::class org.spongepowered.test.test$Parent
false::false
==============================================
class org.spongepowered.test.test$Child::class org.spongepowered.test.test$Parent

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When is .getClass able to return an Object.class?

<s>I **know** it's possible, because we get many bug reports that contain that logging.</s>

Comment: https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeCommon/commit/704ef84398255d66da104e2b43dec7f2c2aa40c3#diff-0570d221b4c69a232692ff6be6369ea3R108

Comment: Thanks, I think this question might be unsuitable to SO after seeing that, but I'll leave it open just so someone can do "It's when it's called on Object ya dummy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.getClass()` returns

> The `Class` object that represents the runtime class of this object.

([Object API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--))

That will be `java.lang.Object.class` if and only if the object's class is exactly `java.lang.Object` (not a subclass).  This method is `final`, so you can rely on every object providing that implementation.

You may, however, also be interested in `Class.isAssignableFrom()` if you are looking for a way to determine reflectively whether one class is a superclass  of another.